# Bootstrap-Sass: Glyphicons showing as rectangles on production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, sass, asset-pipeline

See the top right "admin" icon on http://base.sirius.uberspace.de/en.

When setting

```
config.assets.compile = true
```

they're showing correctly, but I guess that's not the perfect solution, is it?

Setting

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( '.woff', '.eot', '.svg', '.ttf' )
```

doesn't change anything; my mina deployment also does a precompile, as suggested:

```
invoke :'rails:assets_precompile'
```

So how could this be solved?

I'm using Rails 4.1.

Comment: this is a common issue with subdomains, allow your fonts in cors

Comment: I see no issues in the console. I assume everything to be loaded is loaded.

Comment: Uberspace is fast - do you know which datacenter they use?

Comment: @apneadiving, what do you mean with "allow your fonts in cors"?

Comment: http://schock.net/articles/2013/07/03/hosting-web-fonts-on-a-cdn-youre-going-to-need-some-cors/